# How to get the height of last row added in a TableView [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TableView` defined in my FXML file and, naturally, an `ObservableList` linked to it. When the `ObservableList` get a new entry, a new row appears on the `TableView`.

The problem is: I don't want any scrollbar on the `TableView` but it appears when I get a lot of entries in the table. And I can't use **fixedCellSize** because each row has a different height.

I'd like to calculate the height of each row when I get a new entry, how is it possible considering that I don't have any `TableColumn`s defined in my java code? (All of them are defined in the FXML file).

```xml
<TableView fx:id="table" mouseTransparent="true" prefHeight="230.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="COLUMN 1">
                    <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="property1" /></cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="COLUMN 2">
                    <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="property2" /></cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="COLUMN 3">
                    <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="property3" /></cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="345.0" text="COLUMN 4">
                    <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="property4" /></cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
    <columnResizePolicy><TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" /></columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
```

```
 @FXML private TableView<MyObject> table;
    private ObservableList<MyObject> data;

    public MyController() {
        super("/myFXML.fxml");
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        data = table.getItems();   
        MyModel model = new MyModel(data);
    }
```

This class, of course, extends a controller used for each component. And in the `MyModel` class I get the entries in the `ObservableList` (I don't have any reference there to the `TableView`). Everything works fine, I just want to understand if it's possible to calculate the height of the rows dynamically.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just to grow the tableview to do not have the vertical scrollbar?

Comment: @DVarga Not only. If the sum of every row's height reach the height of the TableView, I will start to delete the first rows (first entries in the ObservableList) with a LIFO strategy. I'm currently trying to figure out how it's possible to get a reference to a TableCell (this one has the getHeight() method) from a TableView or a TableColumn. I don't know if there are other way.

Comment: It's going to be pretty difficult to do this. The only chance you have to get a reference to a `TableCell` (or `TableRow`) is in the cell factory or row factory that creates them. Of course, these are reused for different items, or used as empty cells, as the content of the table changes. So in theory you could register listeners with the cells when they're created and try to keep track of everything, but such code would be really fragile. Depending on how much functionality you need from the table, it might be better to implement this with something like a `GridPane`.